# Use !default value with @use in SCSS

Tags: sass

I am having some difficulty overwriting `!default` values in SCSS while using `@use`. When I use `@import` instead of `@use` it behaves correctly but while using `@use` the console gives an error (*This module and the new module both define a variable named "$variable-name"*).

When I change the variable inside the same file where I assign the variable to an element it behaves **correctly**:

```css
// variables/variable.scss
$color-accent: red !default;

// variables/index.scss
@forward ./variable.scss;

// change.scss
@use './variables/index' as *;
$color-accent: blue;
body {
  background-color: $color-accent;
}

// body background color is blue
```

But when I try overwriting it in a seperate file it **won't** work:

```css
// change.scss
$color-accent: blue;

// variables/index.scss
@forward ./variable.scss;
@forward ./change.scss;

// base.scss
@use './variables/index' as *;
body {
  background-color: $color-accent;
}

// main.scss
@use './base';

// error: Two forwarded modules both define a variable named $color-accent
```

Also, when I only `@forward` the `variable.scss` and `@use` the `change.scss` in the `main.scss` file it doesn't give the right outcome (*body background color stays red without an error*).

Does anyone have a suggestion? All help is appreciated.

Joop

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error is where you used two `@forward` in `index.scss` and these two files have variables with the same name. Just loading the `change.scss` file with `@import` can solve the problem.

More Information about the difference between `@import`, `@use` and `@forward` is here: https://www.liquidlight.co.uk/blog/use-and-import-rules-in-scss/.

```
// variables/index.scss
@forward "./variable.scss";
@import "./change.scss";
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked indeed. Was hoping for a solution without using **@import** at all, I believe I read it will be removed in the future. But this will do for now. Appreciate the help.